# How can we find n points on a plane so that as many pairs of points as possible have the same distance?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-constructions

There are $n$ points on the plane, and we need to maximize the number of pairs of points which have the same Euclidean distance.

Comment: See work related to Erdos' Unit Distance Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph#Counting_unit_distances

Comment: $P(0)=P(1)=0; P(2)=1; P(3)=3; P(4)=5; P(5)=7; \ldots$

Comment: $P(6)=9; P(7)=12; \ldots$

Comment: I assume "unordered pairs of different points".

Comment: The subsection of the Wiki page @MarkLewko linked to changed its name to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph#Number_of_edges

Answer (score 14):

The number is tabulated at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A186705). It seems that it's only known up to $n=14$ (and some scattered larger values). Links are given there to some papers on the topic. Evidently, no one knows how to do it for general $n$.

Also discussed on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575268/maximally-dense-unit-distance-graphs).

Comment: Hey, I am glad, thank you. I knew also P(8)=14 but didn't want to risk it.

Comment: There aren't any values bigger than 14 for which it would be known, see the table at the end of http://www1.pub.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/eurocg2020/data/uploads/papers/eurocg20_paper_85.pdf.