# Maximal number of times distance $1$ can occur among $n$ points in the plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry

For $n\in\mathbb N$, let $f(n)$ be the maximal number of times distance $1$ can occur among $n$ points in the plane:
$$
f(n) = \max_{ \{ x_1,\ldots,x_n \} \subset \mathbb R^2} \# \big \{ i<j : \| x_i-x_j \| =1 \big \}.
$$

What is the asymptotic growth of $f(n)$?
Is $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)/n=\infty$?

---

The function $f(n)$ starts very much like A047932:
0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 19, 21, 24, ...
but eventually grows faster.

Comment: @SamHopkins Indeeed, my question is a duplicate. What is the usual way of dealing with this? (I keep the question up, but it gets closed?)

Comment: It can be closed as a duplicate if 5 people vote for that option for closure.

Comment: But you can also delete it, in fact, it think even the duplicate could be deleted as this is such a well-known problem that can be found with a minimal amount of searching online. Ps. Your function values are incorrect from 16.

Comment: @domotorp: it is true that this is a very well-known problem; yet searching for it can be a little bit tricky because the related but different Erdös *distinct distances* problem is slightly more famous, and so comes up first when searching.

Comment: @Sam: Entering the title of the question to google returns first the paper by Erdős where this question is formulated: https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1946-03.pdf Also at the top is this other mathoverflow question, asking the very same thing: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355227/how-can-we-find-n-points-on-a-plane-so-that-as-many-pairs-of-points-as-possible

Comment: @domotorp I find the tone of your comment slightly hurtful. Yes - my question is duplicate. But it feels like you're almost angry at me... that you feel that, because I wasn't aware of Erdös' work, that makes me a bad person. Please be mindful of other members of the community (in this case me) when you post your comments.

Comment: Dear André, please take no offense, I'm not angry with you at all! I'm sorry if you've found my tone harsh, but it wasn't even addressed to you. I'm just trying to convince Sam Hopkins that this problem is very easy to find.